# AVD refuses to start even though KVM is correctly installed and BIOS support enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, kvm

As is seen from the screenshot, from my PC running Ubuntu 16.04 **(32-bit)**, with AMD A10 processor, with HW-virtualization (SVM) enabled in BIOS. In spite of correct installation of kvm, AVD keeps flagging the warning about HAXM needing Genuine Intel processor, and trying to start any Android Device emulator VM, tells me that KVM is required to run this AVD.

Here is how I check kvm correct installation:

```
icarus@getafix:/opt/android-studio$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
icarus@getafix:/opt/android-studio$ sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

The only thing remaining, that I can think of is that mine is a 32-bit Ubuntu installation (due to some legacy stuff), and not 64-bit. Could that then be the issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the steps for my Debian machine to run Emulator

- Open Bios option, Mostly its by pressing f1 key or f1+delete or Alt + f4 (At the time of machine boot up) all it depends on which company's desktop or laptop you are using.
- Go to Advance option
- CPU setup
- **Enable two option there**

  1. intel(R) virtualisation tech
  2. VT-d

Comment: As you might notice in my question, I've already enabled the BIOS settings for HW virtualization support. The same is visible in Ubuntu as well, as found in /proc/cpuinfo.